# error al compilar y ejecutar en cmd

Tags: java

hace pocos dias comence mi estudio y soy principiante sobre java, este es el codigo que use para inicar y al compilar.

```
public class ernesto{
  public static void main(String args[]){


System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al inicar y compilar el codigo, me sale este problema.

agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto

Comment: Lo que muestras no es un error de compilación sino que no encuentra el archivo en la ruta especificada, donde lo guardaste?

Comment: esta en el escritorio, al abrir la ubicación de "Desktop" con el código  "dir" en cmd aparece el archivo, pero al seleccionarlo con el javac me sigue apareciendo ese error

Comment: Si el archivo se encuentra en la ubicación: `C:\Users\DONATO\Desktop`, debes usar `cd desktop` en el shell y luego usas `javac ernesto.java`.

Comment: me sirvió mucho tu consejo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar la ruta en donde guardaste el archivo ernesto.java? De esa forma, asumo se encuentra en c:\Users\DONATO\ernesto.java pero pareciera no estar presente, o bien tener acceso restringido.